# How to open /var/www/html/ in PhpStorm

Tags: apache, phpstorm, fedora, jetbrains-ide, flatpak

I installed LAMP on Fedora 36, it's running fine. But the folder `/var/www/` is not showing in the 'open folder' menu in PhpStorm `/var/` is.

I also couldn't find `/opt/` when I used XAMPP, that's why I installed LAMPP stack.

PhpStorm was installed trough Flatpak.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How did you instal it? Flatpack or alike? If so -- try JetBrains Toolbox instead. https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/

Comment: @LazyOne I installed it using the Fedora Flatpak repo, I just installed the Toolbox and this worked, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, it's Flatpack installation issue/limitation. You can try granting it a full filesystem access (by default it has a limited one; you will also have issues with accessing some other tools). I'm not a Linux user so cannot really help here .. but look at `sudo flatpak override com.jetbrains.PhpStorm --filesystem=host` kind of command...

Comment: Also: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71292700/using-snapd-instead-of-flatpak-in-linux-mint 2) https://stackoverflow.com/q/71587716/783119 3) https://stackoverflow.com/a/59666752/783119 4) https://stackoverflow.com/q/60318660/783119 5) https://stackoverflow.com/a/73225038/783119